# Printing main method in Scala3(Dotty) gave value as Main$$$Lambda ... Why?

Tags: scala, methods, program-entry-point, println, scala-3

I wrote a code below in Scala .

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(main) 
  }
}
```

It gave output as :
`Main$$$Lambda$3/1543727556@3930015a`
*Why is this value returned ?*

Also, When I wrote a simple method like one below :

```
def wow(): Unit = {
  println(wow)
}
```

But it gives compilation error.

Comment: In 2.13.6 vice versa the former doesn't compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qOF01CXXQ4abNIk3YOwraw and the latter does https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Mmwk2kpuR1m6Ki4PvXW2iA It's about transforming a method into a lambda and printing the lambda.

Comment: I am using Scala3 to compile the code and In IntelliJ IDE.
@DmytroMitin But why converted into lambda , and then why only main method ?

Comment: Ok, good to know. It's still about transforming a method into a lambda and printing the lambda. There is a difference when there are method parameters and there are no. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/l0qcTOb8TkyvmPEbFJtSrA https://scastie.scala-lang.org/x0rV5Al1SjOqXg6gykND7g

Comment: Add parameters to `wow` and you'll see https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kg5n08LdShamkTAXIOQ6bg

Comment: Please see http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/eta-expansion.html

Comment: Or transform method `wow` into a lambda with explicit underscore https://scastie.scala-lang.org/aSgnFNSxSTOeIslW2ZCkUw